# Is exit status observable behavior?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, program-entry-point, exit, exit-code

C 2018 5.1.2.3 6 says:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input.
>
> This is the observable behavior of the program.

On the face of it, this does not include the exit status of the program.

Regarding `exit(status)`, 7.22.4.4 5 says:

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of `status` is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status *successful termination* is returned. If the value of `status` is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status *unsuccessful termination* is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

The standard does not tell us this is part of the observable behavior. Of course, it makes no sense for this `exit` behavior to be a description purely of C’s abstract machine; returning a value to the environment has no meaning unless it is observable in the environment. So my question is not so much whether the exit status is observable as whether this is a defect in the C standard’s definition of observable behavior. Or is there text somewhere else in the standard that applies?

Comment: Are you really asking if the optimizer could do anything with exit?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: No.

Comment: It's remarquable: I have read this verbiage several time, and never had I seen what was *not* written. And I would have told anyone that it was written! And C++ has the [same verbiage](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#6)

Comment: If the exit status is returned to the host environment, then surely `exit()` is a function which accesses a volatile object?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths What do you mean by "volatile"? Data used by the kernel?

Comment: @curiousguy: An object that may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation, or have other unknown side effects.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Calling `exit()` isn't "unknown to the implementation". Setting the memory that indicates the exit value does *not* in itself produce a side effect: it isn't a hardware register.

Comment: @curiousguy: Setting the exit status is a change in the state of the execution environment, so it's a side effect by definition. And setting the exit status has unknown side effects, because neither the implementation nor the program has any idea what the calling process is doing to do in response to that exit status (necessarily, because the program will have exited before that response occurs). The act of calling a function which has side effects is, in itself, a side effect, according to the standard.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Would you also call argc and argv "volatile objects"?

Comment: @curiousguy: No, since they don't fall under the definition.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s possible to piece this together to see the answer fall under the first bullet point of § 5.1.2.3.6:

> Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the
>   rules of the abstract machine

Looking further, § 3.1 defines “access” as:

> to read or modify the value of an object

and § 3.15 defines an “object” as:

> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of
>   which can represent values

The standard, curiously, contains no definition of “volatile object”. It does contain a definition of “an object that has volatile-qualified type” in § 6.7.3.6:

> An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways
>   unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects.
>   Therefore any expression referring to such an object shall be
>   evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, as
>   described in 5.1.2.3.

It seems not unreasonable to infer that an object that has volatile-qualified type has that qualification precisely to inform the compiler that it is, in fact, a volatile object, so I don’t think it’s stretching things too far to use this wording as the basis of a definition for “volatile object” itself, and define a volatile object as an object which may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects.

§ 5.1.2.3.2 defines “side effect” as follows:

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or
>   calling a function that does any of those operations are all side
>   effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

So I think we can piece this together as follows:

1. Returning the exit status to be returned to the host environment is
   clearly a change in the state of the execution environment, as the
   execution environment after having received, for example,
   `EXIT_SUCCESS`, is necessarily in a different state that it would be
   had it received, for example, `EXIT_FAILURE`. Returning the exit
   status is therefore a side effect per § 5.1.2.3.2
2. `exit()` is a function that does this, so calling `exit()` is therefore
   itself also a side effect per § 5.1.2.3.2.
3. The standard obviously gives us no details of the inner workings of
   `exit()` or of what mechanism `exit()` will use to return that value to
   the host environment, but it’s nonsensical to suppose that accessing
   an object will not be involved, since objects are regions of data
   storage in the execution environment whose contents can represent
   values, and the exit status is a value.
4. Since we don’t know what, if anything, the host environment will do
   in response to that change in state (not least because our program
   will have exited before it happens), this access has an unknown side
   effect, and the object accessed is therefore a volatile object.
5. Since calling `exit()` accesses a volatile object, it is observable
   behavior per § 5.1.2.3.6.

This is consistent with the normal understanding of objects that have volatile-qualified types, namely that we can’t optimize away accesses to such objects if we cannot determine that no needed side effects will be omitted because the observable behavior (in the normal everyday sense) may be affected if we do. There is no visible object of volatile-qualified type in this case, of course, because the volatile object is question is accessed internally by `exit()`, and `exit()` obviously need not even be written in C. But there seems undoubtedly to be a volatile object, and § 5.1.2.3 refers specifically (three times) to volatile objects, and not to objects of volatile-qualified type (and other than a footnote to § 6.2.4.2, this is the only place in the standard volatile objects are referred to.)

Finally, this seems to be the only reading that renders § 5.1.2.3.6 intelligible, as intuitively we’d expect the “observable behavior” of C programs using only the facilities described by the standard to be that which loosely:

- Changes memory in a way that’s visible outside of the program itself;
- Changes the contents of files (which are by definition visible outside of the
  program itself); and
- Affects interactions with interactive devices

which seems to be essentially what § 5.1.2.3.6 is trying to get at.

**Edit**

There seems to be some little controversy in the comments apparently centered around the ideas that the exit status may be passed in registers, and that registers cannot be objects. This objection (no pun intended) is trivially refutable:

1. Objects can be declared with the `register` storage class specifier, and such objects can be designated by lvalues;
2. Memory-mapped registers, fairly ubiquitous in embedded programming, provide as clear a demonstration as any that registers can be objects, can have addresses, and can be designated by lvalues. Indeed, memory-mapped registers are one of the most common uses of `volatile`-qualified types;
3. `mmap()` shows that even file contents can sometimes have addresses and be objects.

In general, it's a mistake to believe that objects can only reside in, or that "addresses" can only refer to, locations in core memory, or banks of DRAM chips, or anything else that one might conventionally refer to as "memory" or "RAM". *Any* component of the execution environment that's capable of storing a value, including registers, could be an object, could potentially have an address, and could potentially be designated by an lvalue, and this is why the definition of "object" in the standard is cast in such deliberately wide terms.

Additionally, sections such as § 5.3.2.1.9 go to some lengths to draw a distinction between "values of the actual objects" and "[values] specified by the abstract semantics", indicating that actual objects are real things existing in the execution environment distinct from the abstract machine, and are things which the specification does indeed closely concern itself with, as the definition of "object" in § 3.15 makes clear. It seems untenable to maintain a position that the standard concerns itself with such actual objects up to and only up to the point at which a standard library function is invoked, at which point all such concerns evaporate and such matters suddenly become "outside C".

Comment: What makes you think that anything represented by bytes and written by the program code is an object?

Comment: @curiousguy: What makes you think I said that?

Comment: What do you try to prove with "_since objects are regions of data storage in the execution environment whose contents can represent values_"? How do you know exit involves writing to an object?

Comment: @curiousguy: What in "The standard obviously gives us no details of the inner workings of `exit()` or of what mechanism `exit()` will use to return that value to the host environment" is unclear to you?

Comment: In Unix like systems, `exit()` will probably 1) run `atexit` stuff 2) calls `_exit()`, a system call. Which of these two likely involves a C object? My point is that all your arguments are a) made believe and b) circular

Comment: @curiousguy: If you can think of a way to return an exit status to the host environment without ever using any regions of storage in the execution environment, I'd be interested to hear it. For sure no Unix-like systems will do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186322/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-paul-griffiths).

Comment: Technically, it seems that "those operations are all side effects which are changes in the state of the execution environment" says that "those operations" are "side effects" AND "changes in the state of the execution environment", since the "which" introduces a restrictive clause. So you can't deduce that "change in the state of the execution environment" implies a "side effect".

Comment: @jinawee: Looks like I accidentally removed a comma in my extract from the standard when removing a footnote reference. It actually reads "...are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment". This section is defining "side effects" as "changes in the state of the execution environment", so technically you're right that you can't *deduce* it, because it's true by definition.

Comment: 1. and 2. may be feasible (`exit` could be understood as changing the environment, and “side effects” could mean changes to the environment, not just those explicitly listed in 5.1.2.3 2. But 3. is not correct; it reasons that a value is an object, which is not correct. Values are frequently handled in C without being objects; many values are not lvalues.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It doesn't attempt such a simplistic reasoning. If a value is returned, then it must be made available to something (e.g. in a normal Unix-like system the exit status will be kept around for collection through one of the `wait()` family). If it's made available to something, then it's being stored, and that's what makes it an object. State is being changed when an exit status is returned.

Comment: No, the exit status could be completely conveyed in registers, never in memory, or even by other means. Even if it is placed in memory, the fact that a value is written to memory, this is now outside the bounds of the C specification. The statement “it’s nonsensical to suppose that accessing an object will not be involved, since objects are regions of data storage in the execution environment whose contents can represent values, and the exit status is a value” is bogus. You should have stopped at 2. That is as good as this line of reasoning is going to get; the rest of `exit` is outside C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Registers would fall under the definition, footnote 12 to that very section gives an example of setting floating point status flags as being "side effects" within the definition of C. The fact that the execution environment itself, which exists prior to program startup and continues to exist after program termination, is referred to frequently in the standard contradicts the assertion that such considerations must be "outside C". C programs, like all programs, exist for the sole purpose of changing the environment in which they run, and the standard recognizes this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: For example, the Linux x86_64 calling convention has almost all function arguments passed in registers, but the fact that this is, or can be, done doesn't mean function parameters cease to be objects. It's a non-sequitur.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: The fact that changes to things are considered side effects does not mean the things are objects. Function parameters are objects within the C model. Implementing them as registers is an “as if” optimization; conflating the use of registers to implement them with a claim that registers qualify as objects is specious. As I wrote, you should have stopped with 2.; it is not unreasonable to interpret `exit` as changing the environment and that being a side effect. It is unreasonable to assert that the exit value must be an object or must be stored in an object.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: OK, we're talking about interpretations of the standard and you're under no obligation to agree with mine. However, I stand by my interpretation that it's meaningless to claim that returning an exit status doesn't involve a change of state in the execution environment, that such a change of state by definition must entail a change in a stored value in the execution environment, and that since C defines objects simply as "regions of data storage in the execution environment" without further qualification, it must therefore involve access to an object.

Comment: what about `return` ing a value from main , without calling the exit function? That also sets the exit status

Comment: I was skeptical of inferring the existence of extra objects not specifically required to exist by the Standard - until I came across a footnote in 6.7.3 Type Qualifiers: "This applies to those objects that behave as if they were defined with qualified types, even if they are never actually defined as objects in the program (such as an object at a memory-mapped input/output address)."

Comment: @M.M: Since returning from `main()` is equivalent to calling `exit()` with the same value, I don't think it makes any difference to the rationale which of the two is chosen, as the same process will be performed.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths "_calling convention has almost all function arguments passed in registers_" only for the purpose of copying the values; when the compiler needs the address of these objects, they are allocated on the stack

Comment: @curiousguy: So? The C standard doesn't require an implementation to have a stack. The address may never be taken at all in which case the value would never be placed on the stack for a leaf call, and if the compiler could determine that that register was not used for a different purpose by a nested function call, it could just as easily assign it a mapped address instead. This practice has nothing to do with the fact that those objects are registers per se, but rather with the inconvenience in the general case of using fixed locations to implement objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths The C standard doesn't require registers either. Someone mentioned registers. Do you claim that if a value is written somewhere by a program, that value is stored in an object? If that isn't what you claim, I don't understand what you claim.

Comment: @curiousguy: I'm not sure what you're having difficulty understanding. I claim that objects are regions of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values, just as the standard defines them to be. Further, I claim that registers can and often do fall within this definition, in general because they self-evidently do, and more specifically for the reasons I give in the edit to the answer.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths That is *not* the definition of an C or C++ object. If it was, then any region written to by the program would be an object. An object is only created by a C or C++ declaration or instruction.

Comment: @curiousguy: It's exactly the definition of an object. You can look it up yourself in the C standard, under section § 3, "Terms, definitions and symbols", subsection § 3.15, "Object", conveniently quoted in my answer. If you're going to attempt to deny this demonstrable fact in a question directly asking about the text of the standard, then there's no point continuing this line of questioning any further.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths It cannot be the definition, obviously. Any region of storage would be an object. This is crazy.

Comment: @curiousguy: If one were to delete paragraph 7 of N1570 section 6.5, and said that every region of storage will, throughout its lifetime, contain overlapping objects of every type that will fit, with changes to any object affecting the underlying storage and changes to the storage affecting all objects that include it, that would be consistent with the definition of "object" and also with the way compilers work when optimizations based upon 6.5p7 are disabled.  What's crazy about that?

Answer (score -1):

The exit status is supposed to be observable to the host environment that runs the implementation.  Whether the host environment does anything with this is outside the scope of the standard.

Comment: This question is marked with the language-lawyer tag: It is a question specifically about what the standard says. Can you cite a source, in the standard or the committee deliberations or a similarly informative document, that the exit status is supposed to be observable?

Comment: 5.1.2.2.3: "If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument;11) reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status **returned to the host environment** is unspeciﬁed."

Comment: Since observable behavior is explicitly listed in 5.1.2.3 6 and does not include the exit status, why should we think this text in 5.1.2.2.3 is observable behavior and not merely a description of the abstract machine?

Comment: Because the exit status has to exist somewhere in order for it to be passed to the host environment, otherwise having an argument in the exit function is meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

I have read the `system` function documentation (7.22.4.8 The system function). It contains:

> Returns
>
> If the argument is a null pointer, the system function returns nonzero only if a
>   command processor is available. If the argument is not a null pointer, and the system
>   function does return, it returns an implementation-defined value.

It looks like the standard made provision for a system where a C program (or more generally a user defined command) could not start another command, and/or where where a command would not return anything to its caller. In that latter case, the exit value would not be observable (in the common sense).

In this interpretation, the *observability* of the exit value would just be implementation defined. And it would be consistent with it not being explicitely cited in the observable behaviour of a program.

I can remember of an old system ([Solar 16](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_(ordinateur))) from the 70's where commands were started with `call` for standard commands or `run` for user commands, and where parameters could only be passed on *sub-commands* after a specific request from the program. No C compiler existed there, but if someone had managed to implement one, the return value would not have been observable.